# failed to import angular external lib

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-modules

i have 2 libs.

1 - ui-templates

2 - ui-components

To import ui-templates from app, im doing that:

```
import {UiTemplatesModule} from '@growerdiaries-web/ui-templates';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, UiTemplatesModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And everything works fine.

But now, i want to use some components of ui-components into ui-templates.

To do that, on ui-templates module, i created this code:

```
//if i use @growerdiaries-web/ui-components dosent works. Dosent find the reference.
import {UiComponentsModule} from '../../../ui-components/src/lib/ui-components.module';

import { LoginTemplateComponent } from './login-template/login-template.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, UiComponentsModule],
  declarations: [
    LoginTemplateComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginTemplateComponent
  ],
})
export class UiTemplatesModule {}
```

Why module cant find the reference from ui-components library direcly? Im doing something wrong?

ui-components module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button/button.component';
import { InputComponent } from './input/input.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    ButtonComponent,
    InputComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ButtonComponent,
    InputComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
})
export class UiComponentsModule {}
```

Comment: And where are you trying to use the exported components of UiComponentsModule ? With this setup you should be able the use it inside LoginTemplateComponent.

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to clear the visual studio code cache. Resolved.